# Random Forest Prediction with Lags

Tags: r, dynamic, random-forest, lag, prediction

```
library(randomForest)    
library(dyn)
set.seed(123)
tz <- zoo(cbind(Y = rnorm(10), x = rnorm(10)))
tz[10, "Y"] <- NA
rr <- tz
rr<-cbind(`lag(Y, -1)` = lag(rr$Y, -1),rr)
fit <- dyn$randomForest(Y ~ lag(Y,-1) +x , tz, subset = seq_len(10-1))
pred <-predict(fit, newdata=rr)
```

I am trying to get the random forest to predict the 10th observation, however it keeps coming back as NA. I think it has something to do with the lag value, but am not sure how this works. Anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: your code is not reproducible...

Comment: sorry I forgot the random forest package. It should work now.

Comment: still not reproducible...

Comment: would you mind elaborating?

Comment: Thank you for your help and sorry for bothering you. I restarted R and had no issues, I would like to fix it, but I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: did you clear your workspace?

Comment: I cleared it and went from R studio to Rx64 and Rx32 and got the same results in both

Comment: you dont get an error with ``rr<-cbind(`lag(Y, -1)` = lag(rr$Y, -1),rr)`` ?

Comment: No error it made the following for me:    
lag(Y, -1)           Y          x
1           NA -0.56047565  1.2240818
2  -0.56047565 -0.23017749  0.3598138
3  -0.23017749  1.55870831  0.4007715
4   1.55870831  0.07050839  0.1106827
5   0.07050839  0.12928774 -0.5558411
6   0.12928774  1.71506499  1.7869131
7   1.71506499  0.46091621  0.4978505
8   0.46091621 -1.26506123 -1.9666172
9  -1.26506123 -0.68685285  0.7013559
10 -0.68685285          NA -0.4727914

Comment: my apologies I was copy pasting your code into a text editor i rarely use and how the apostrophes were transcribed was affecting my output. fixed it, check my post below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were adding an unnecessary line of code.

```
set.seed(123)
tz <- zoo(cbind(Y = rnorm(10), x = rnorm(10)))

tz <- zoo(cbind(Y = rnorm(10), x = rnorm(10)))

rr <- tz
rr<-cbind(`lag(Y, -1)` = lag(rr$Y, -1),rr)
fit <- dyn$randomForest(Y ~ lag(Y,-1) +x , tz, subset = seq_len(10-1))
predict(fit, newdata=rr)
  1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9          10 
 0.65469597  0.63274585  0.52821489 -0.58116470 -0.28673507  0.73862391 -0.31800427 -0.59019492 -0.34942432 -0.02772214
```

That extra line is `tz[10, "Y"] <- NA`. If you remove that, like in above, the 10th element is predicted.

Comment: Thanks. Is there away to predict the 10th observation if I did not know what Y was?

Comment: No because you need that information to obtain predicted values. If you find my answer acceptable please accept the answer so the question is resolved and/or consider up voting my answer if you found it helpful. Thanks! By accepting an answer, you will also get back some points you lost due to negative responses to your post.

Comment: Also if you want additional help on randomforest predictions, consider scanning Cross Validated's forums (sister site to SO but for more stats related questions). Good luck and welcome to Stack Overflow!